# $F(h)=h \circ \phi$, $F:C^B \to C^A$, $\phi : A\to B$, prove F is surjective

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, predicate-logic

Got a question as the following, could solve the first, would appreciate getting some help for the second :

Let there be $F(h)=h \circ \phi$, $F:C^B \to C^A$, $\phi : A\to B$.
Assuming there's in C more then one element, prove:

- if F is injective then $\phi$ is surjective.
- if F is surjective then $\phi$ is injective.

So for "if F is injective then $\phi$ is surjective", I proved by contrapositivity.
I assumed that F is injective but $\phi$ isn't surjective, then exists $b \in B$ such that there is no $a\in A$ that fulfills $\phi(a)=b$.
Secondly, I define $f_1, f_2 \in C^B$ that are equal except for element 'b' ($\in B$), meaning that: $f_1(b)=c_1$ $f_2(b)=c_2$.
Now, because F is injective $F(f_1)=F(f_2)$, then $f_1 = f_2$ though $f_1(b)\neq f_2(b)$. Then we get contradiction, then $\phi$ must be surjective.

Now, about "If F is surjective then $\phi$ is injective", I'm not quite sure how to do that. I also think it should be done by the contrapositive path.  Should I define some function $g\in C^A$ that there is no $h\in C^B$ that gives $F(h)=g$ because of defining $\phi$ as non injective?

Would appreciate your help.

Comment: Yes, contraposition sounds like the right way to go for the second part too.

Comment: @HenningMakholm So I need to define $g\in C^A$ such that there is no $h\in C^B$ that gives me g. had trouble finding such one, any ideas?

Comment: x @Ami: Correct. Note that you know that $\phi$ is not injective -- so there are $a_1$ and $a_2$ such that $\phi(a_1)=\phi(a_2)$. This means that $h\circ\phi$ will always map $a_1$ and $a_2$ to the same element of $C$ ...

Answer (score 1):

First, make $f_1$ and $f_2$ completely concrete: indeed we pick distinct $c_1 \neq c_2$ in $C$ (which our assumption tells us we can do). We have one unreachable $b \in B$. Define $f_1(x) = c_1 = f_2(x)$ for all $x \in B\setminus\{b\}$, $f_1(b) = c_1, f_2(b) = c_2$. Now explicitly show that $F(f_1) = F(f_2)$, etc.

Now suppose that $\phi$ is not injective, this gives us positive info: there are $a_1 \neq a_2$ in $A$ such that $\phi(a_1) = b = \phi(a_2)$ for some $b \in B$.

This means that all compositions with $\phi$ (which is what $F$ is) will do the same thing to $a_1$ and $a_2$. So this limits the kind of functions we can get as an image. Find a concrete (!) function that does not do this and then it cannot be an image of $F$ for this $\phi$.

Comment: how can you know whether there're $a_1, a_2$ in A? you know about C, but know nothing about A.

Comment: You assume non-injectivity (by the contraposition). So you have at least two elements.

Comment: Got you. So I can define g as follows:
$g(a_1)=c_1$ $g(a_2)=c_2$, and for every other $a\in A$ g would be $g(a)=c$ for some arbitary $c\in C$. but as we said $\phi (a_1)=b= \phi (a_2)$ -> then it takes us to contradiction?

Comment: Suppose that $F(f) = g$ for some $f \in C^B$. What happens at $a_1$ and $a_2$?

Comment: at $a_1, a_2$ I get $g(a_1)=g(a_2)$?

Comment: Contrary to how $g$ was chosen

Comment: you mean contrary to that we chose g to be as following:
$g(a_1)=c_1, g(a_2)=c_2$, $g(a)=c$ for some arbitrary $c\in C$ and for every other $a\in A$?

Comment: Yes. Evaluate $F(f)(a_1)=g(a_1)$ etc. $F(f)(a_1) = (f \circ \phi))(a_1) = f(\phi(a_1)) = f(b)$. Same for $F(f)(a_2) = g(a_2) = f(b)$. So indeed $g(a_) = g(a_2)$ contradiction. No such $f$ can exist.